# Prevent shell script from exiting on certain command when set -e is enabled

Tags: linux, bash

I have shell script where i have set -e in first line and I am checking for binary in path using `where kubectl`. If kubectl is not present on system then this command returns non-zero error hence entire script break. I want to silence functionality of `set -e` while running `where` command. Is there a way I can protect script from exiting or in other words ignore return code of selective command in script?

Comment: use `set +e` to do that

Comment: I tried that out but on setting it back it doesn't exit on error

Comment: @prashant: Use the logic as mentioned in the other answer. `where kubectl || : `. Even better to avoid the error statement `where kubectl 2>/dev/null || : `

Comment: [Don't use `set -e` - ever.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: @dennis what is the best solution to it

Comment: ok got it, I missed the link you mention